# Alteryx WorkFlow for deleting column values from different rows based on certain column conditions

Tags: alteryx

Hi I have a data table like this

```
    Group  CODE Quantity Value FLAG

     A      AP    10      100    1
     A      AM    10      200    1
     A      AP    03       50    2
     B      AM    50      150    2
```

1. I want to check if the column values for GROUP & CODE are equal & FLAG values are different, Then i want to subract Value with FLAG 1 to Value with Flag 2 and update it to new column as Delta.
2. If there exist no match with the column values for Group & Code then just update "0" to new Column as Delta.

The output data will look like this

```
    Group  CODE Quantity Value FLAG Delta

     A      AP    10      100    1    50
     A      AM    10      200    1     0
     A      AP    03       50    2     0
     B      AM    50      150    2     0
```

I would like to do this in Alteryx. Thanks for your support & Help

Comment: Send into filter on `FLAG = 1`, then join each side of the filter output together, on GROUP and CODE. Then use a Formula tool to calculate `delta`, and then join back to original dataset.

Comment: Thanks johnjps, I am now doing the same, thank you